# React Redux error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm using axios with react redux. I get this error when there is successful post.Is this the right way to handle error in axios and redux. If not please guide me.My reference links [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) ,[how to deal with errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439019/redux-promise-with-axios-and-how-do-deal-with-errors) , [error handling in axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/376) .If this question seems obvious ,i apologize.I'm beginner.Thanks in advance.

```
export const landingPageValues=(values)=>{
  return dispatch=>{
    return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/mainData',values)
      .then(res=>{dispatch(mainpageuploadsuccess(res.data))})
      .catch(err=>{dispatch(mainpageuploadfailed(err.response.data.error))})
  }
}
export const mainpageuploadsuccess = (data) =>{
  return {
    type:'MAINPAGE_UPLOAD_SUCCESS',
    mainUploadData:data
  }
}

export const mainpageuploadfailed = (error) =>{
  return {
    type:'MAINPAGE_UPLOAD_FAILED',
    error
  }
}
```

Reducer

```
case 'MAINPAGE_UPLOAD_SUCCESS':
  const {mainUploadData} = action;
  return {
    ...state,
    mainUploadData,
    error:false
  };

  case 'MAINPAGE_UPLOAD_FAILED':
  const {error} = action;
  return {
    ...state,
    error,
    mainUploadData:false
  };
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806333/unable-to-catch-and-log-the-error-response-from-an-axios-request/44806462#44806462

Comment: Also where exactly do you get this error, in .then or .catch.

Comment: Just can you add console.log in both then and catch , not sure if the data mentioned in the error is for res.data or err.response.data

Comment: I think the problem might be in the `/mainData` endpoint, depending on how you construct the response given by said endpoint.

Comment: @Dez thank you so much.Yes, the problem is with the endpoint response.

Answer (score 1):

have removed the return keyword before axios.post

```
export const landingPageValues=(values)=>{
        return dispatch=>{   
              axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/mainData',values)
              .then(res=>{dispatch(mainpageuploadsuccess(res.data))})
              .catch(err=>{dispatch(mainpageuploadfailed(err.response.data.error))}) 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `error` object may not necessary contain the `response` key (eg: when it is a network error).

So you need to add a check before handling error.

```
if (error.response && error.response.data) {
  dispatch(mainpageuploadfailed(err.response.data.error));
}  else {
  handleErrorsElsewhere(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
case 'MAINPAGE_UPLOAD_SUCCESS':
            const {mainUploadData} = action;
            return {
              error:false,
              ...state,
              mainUploadData
            };

            case 'MAINPAGE_UPLOAD_FAILED':
            const {error} = action;
            return {
              mainUploadData:false,
              ...state,
              error,
            };
```

Hope it helped you.

Answer (score -3):

check your server response once. i mean if you are using node js check the response(like res.send()) what you are sending is gonna be your data coming to the front-end